# AWS Auto Scaling Fargate tasks up or down depending on SQS queue length

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

1. I have a long-running containerized process that is a Fargate service.
2. The service uses Squiss poller to poll messages from an AWS SQS queue and handles the messages.
3. I would like to have the service instances process messages and when the queue is drained, I would like the instances to be autoscaled down to zero. (Squiss already handles multiple messages in-flight and since the tasks are long-running, I currently just process one message at a time.)
4. When messages start arriving in the queue, I would like the instances to be auto-scaled up a maximum count of N instances.

I have implemented 1. and 2.

For implementing 3. and 4. how should I configure it? Do I need an AWS lambda function to manage the autoscale up/down or can autoscaling configuration accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need lambda for scale. You need to create CloudWatch metrics for heights and lower messages in the queue. The highest will be used by ECS service to scale out, the lower to scale-in. Then you have to configure your adjust policy when you create your ECS service to use the CloudWatch metrics to take actions either scale-out or scale-in. Have a read at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Using SQS metrics to scale will have business impact for the application. As we scale based on sqs metrics the tasks will span and does the further processing. But if the sqs metrics was reduced the CF alarm will kick in to reduce the ECS tasks to desired state. Will it not kill the task which will be in process? Don't you think that ECS does not know which one to kill as it needs to match the desired state so it can remove any task irrespective of processing or not.

Comment: Instrument your application to be able to use ECS API to have scale in protection enabled with TRUE or FALSE when the messages are picked and processed to be able to terminate tasks safely.